# AppArmor Profile for PowerDNS

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, powerdns

I am currently working on a new authoritative nameserver using powerdns on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS.
I'd like to have AppArmor protecting this service like it did with bind, but when I look in /etc/apparmor.d/, there was no AppArmor profile for this service installed by default.

Any experienced pdns admins know what all files pdns accesses, so I can define a profile?
Or better yet, does anyone HAVE a profile for pdns?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you can't find a profile then make your own.  [AppArmor profiles are pretty easy to make](http://beginlinux.com/twitter/1108-create-a-profile-in-apparmor).

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this in the original question. I will post the profile here.

Comment: Accepted very late, I did end up using aa-genprof when I finally came back to this. Do this.